# use of limit-clause and parent-query-column inside subqueries of SQL

Tags: mysql, join, sql-limit

I want to use limit clause inside the sub-query.At the same time,parent query column should be accessible inside the sub-query.I am using MySQL and want to do something like below:

```
select * from users u1 join (SELECT b1.userid from bids b1 where b1.userid=u1.userid limit 0,4) a1
```

Of-course this is not valid , since b1.authorid is not accessible in this way.

1)I want to limit the result after applying where clause so clearly following is ruled out:

```
select * from users u1 JOIN (SELECT b1.userid from bids b1 limit 0,4) a1 ON b1.userid=u1.userid
```

2)Following is not supported in MySQL ( LIMIT with IN/ANY/EVERY/SOME ):

```
select * from users u1 join bids b2 ON b2.userid IN (SELECT b1.userid from bids b1 where b1.userid=u1.userid limit 0,4)
```

Is there a way for achieving the desired result in MySQL?

SQLFiddle link:
[SQL query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec86c/1)

Let me put the meaning of the query in different way.
Suppose ANS is output, USER is users table and BID is bids table.Representation of the query would be something like this:

```
USER=table(users);
While(USER has next raw) {
  uraw=USER.nextraw;
  BID=table(bids);
  count=0;
  While(BID has next raw) {
    braw=BID.nextraw;
    if(uraw.author < braw.id) {
      if(count>=0) {
        ANS.add(fields from uraw,fields from braw);
      }
      count=count+1;
    }
    if(count>=4) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
return ANS;
```

Comment: If you're still struggling, consider providing a sqlfiddle together with the desired result.

Comment: I have added sqlfiddle as was suggested.

Comment: Good. OK, first thing... LIMIT without ORDER BY is meaningless. What are you actually trying to achieve, and - please re-read my previous comment!!!

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, it's an interesting question, but your test case is a bit flawed, since you're joining on the user ID, thus all the records will have the same user ID, thus selecting only the top 4 has no purpose.

Comment: Let me put it another way.Each user may be involved into one or more bids.Now I want a table containing first four bids of every user.When I say 'first four', I don't mean any specific order (on date or bid-price etc.)I mean natural order (example: SELECT * FROM bids LIMIT 1,4 returns first four bids without ordering on some column). But If you know any way with specific order, please post it.

Comment: I have appended a pseudo-code into the question for making meaning of the query clear.Please go through it.

Comment: See [this link](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) especially the section titled _Select the top N rows from each group_

Comment: [An Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec86c/16) in your case

Comment: There is no such thing as *natural order* - at least not in any reliably consistent sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it support limit in join query. Just change ON ON b1.authorid = a1.id to 
where b1.authorid = a1.id

```
SELECT * FROM books b1 JOIN (SELECT * FROM authors LIMIT 0,4) a1 where b1.authorid = a1.id
```

Comment: thanks for replying.I think We can use LIMIT inside inner queries but using them with parent-query-column seems not possible in MySQL.

Comment: Yes it supports limit in join query. I changed my answer. please see above

Comment: That way, where clause is applied after limit is applied.But the other way around is desired here.That is specified in first problem in the question.

Comment: plz check SELECT * FROM books b1 JOIN (SELECT * FROM authors LIMIT 0,4) a1 where b1.authorid = a1.id

Answer (score 0):

Given your SQL fiddle, something like this should work:

```
 SELECT u.*
      , i.*
      , x.bid
      , x.bid_date
   FROM bids x 
   JOIN bids y 
     ON y.userid = x.userid 
    AND y.bid_date <= x.bid_date 
   JOIN users u
     ON u.userid = x.userid
   JOIN items i
     ON i.itemno = x.itemno
  GROUP 
     BY userid,bid_date
 HAVING COUNT(*) <= 4;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec86c/9).

Comment: As far as desired result is concerned, I want the table that you have posted with one restriction:(first four bids per each user). That's why I am using limit clause.

Comment: @Dukeling - More minimal because you've left out the items table. Is that helpful?

Comment: `items` was left out of the query in the question, so I only thought it appropriate to leave it out of the query in the answer as well, not to mention that it still conveys the basic idea to achieve what was asked, and, given that it has less data, it should show it more clearly. But that's just my opinion.